# configure error for mpfr-3.1.2 missing libgmp but is is in the /usr/lib

Tags: configure, mpfr, linux-from-scratch

I am on step 6.15.1 on linux from scratch. When I am trying to configure the mpfr I am getting an error ...

```
checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... no
configure: error: libgmp not found or uses a different ABI (including static vs shared).
Please read the INSTALL file -- see "In case of problem".
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

If I look in the \usr\lib I have libgmp.{a,la,so,so.10,so.10.1.2} and libgmpxx.{a,la,so,so.4,so.4.3.2} So I not sure what libgmp it is looking for. I have install the "allpatches" from the mpfr web site. I have tried to install the gmp with "ABI=32 .configure ..." and without. The gmp test awk shows a count of 185, so I assume all 185 passed. Any logs will be from my last try of gmp with the "ABI" option.

Here is how I am running the config for mpfr-3.1.2.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr \
--enable-thread-safe \
--docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpfr-3.1.2
```

Here is the run sequence (post was too big so I snipped part of it) :

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by MPFR configure 3.1.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-thread-safe --docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpfr-3.1.2

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = LinuxRemaster
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.2.0-59-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #90-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 7 22:47:22 UTC 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /tools/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

......

pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -ffloat-store  conftest.c >&5
    configure:14478: $? = 0
    configure:14486: result: yes
    configure:14497: checking for recent GMP
    configure:14509: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -ffloat-store  conftest.c >&5
    configure:14509: $? = 0
    configure:14510: result: yes
    configure:14594: checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp
    configure:14619: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -ffloat-store   conftest.c -lgmp   >&5
    /tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    configure:14619: $? = 1
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
    | #define PACKAGE_NAME "MPFR"
    | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "mpfr"
    | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.1.2"
    | #define PACKAGE_STRING "MPFR 3.1.2"
    | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
    | #define PACKAGE_URL ""
    | #define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
    | #define STDC_HEADERS 1
    | #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
    | #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
    | #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
    | #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
    | #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
    | #define HAVE_LOCALE_H 1
    | #define HAVE_WCHAR_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STDARG 1
    | #define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
    | #define HAVE_ALLOCA_H 1
    | #define HAVE_ALLOCA 1
    | #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
    | #define HAVE_VA_COPY 1
    | #define HAVE_MEMMOVE 1
    | #define HAVE_MEMSET 1
    | #define HAVE_SETLOCALE 1
    | #define HAVE_STRTOL 1
    | #define HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY 1
    | #define HAVE_LONG_LONG 1
    | #define HAVE_INTMAX_T 1
    | #define MPFR_HAVE_INTMAX_MAX 1
    | #define MPFR_HAVE_FESETROUND 1
    | #define HAVE_DENORMS 1
    | #define HAVE_ROUND 1
    | #define HAVE_TRUNC 1
    | #define HAVE_FLOOR 1
    | #define HAVE_CEIL 1
    | #define HAVE_NEARBYINT 1
    | #define HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE 1
    | #define HAVE_LDOUBLE_IEEE_EXT_LITTLE 1
    | #define MPFR_USE_THREAD_SAFE 1
    | #define HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME 1
    | #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
    | #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
    | #define HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_MODE 1
    | /* end confdefs.h.  */
    | 
    | /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
    |    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
    |    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
    | #ifdef __cplusplus
    | extern "C"
    | #endif
    | char __gmpz_init ();
    | int
    | main ()
    | {
    | return __gmpz_init ();
    |   ;
    |   return 0;
    | }
    configure:14628: result: no
    configure:14633: error: libgmp not found or uses a different ABI (including static vs shared).
    Please read the INSTALL file -- see "In case of problem".

    ## ---------------- ##
    ## Cache variables. ##
    ## ---------------- ##

    ac_cv_build=i686-pc-linux-gnu
    ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
    ac_cv_c_const=yes
    ac_cv_c_volatile=yes
    ac_cv_env_CC_set=
    ac_cv_env_CC_value=

ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_func_alloca_works=yes
ac_cv_func_gettimeofday=yes
ac_cv_func_memmove=yes
ac_cv_func_memset=yes
ac_cv_func_setlocale=yes
ac_cv_func_strtol=yes
ac_cv_header_dlfcn_h=yes
ac_cv_header_float_h=yes
ac_cv_header_inttypes_h=yes
ac_cv_header_limits_h=yes
ac_cv_header_locale_h=yes
ac_cv_header_memory_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdarg_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdc=yes
ac_cv_header_stdint_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdlib_h=yes
ac_cv_header_string_h=yes
ac_cv_header_strings_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_fpu_h=no
ac_cv_header_sys_stat_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_time_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_types_h=yes
ac_cv_header_time=yes
ac_cv_header_unistd_h=yes
ac_cv_header_wchar_h=yes
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_lib_gmp___gmpz_init=no
ac_cv_lib_m_main=yes
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_EGREP='/tools/bin/grep -E'
ac_cv_path_FGREP='/tools/bin/grep -F'
ac_cv_path_GREP=/tools/bin/grep
ac_cv_path_SED=/tools/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/tools/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/tools/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_CPP='gcc -std=gnu99 -E'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_AR=ar
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_DLLTOOL=dlltool
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_OBJDUMP=objdump
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_RANLIB=ranlib
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_STRIP=strip
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cc_gcc_c_o=yes
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_search_clock_gettime='none required'
ac_cv_type_intmax_t=yes
ac_cv_type_long_double=yes
ac_cv_type_long_long_int=yes
ac_cv_type_size_t=yes
ac_cv_type_union_fpc_csr=no
ac_cv_working_alloca_h=yes
am_cv_CC_dependencies_compiler_type=gcc3
gl_cv_size_max=yes
gmp_cv_c_attribute_mode=yes
lt_cv_ar_at_file=@
lt_cv_archive_cmds_need_lc=no
lt_cv_deplibs_check_method=pass_all
lt_cv_file_magic_cmd='$MAGIC_CMD'
lt_cv_file_magic_test_file=
lt_cv_ld_reload_flag=-r
lt_cv_nm_interface='BSD nm'
lt_cv_objdir=.libs
lt_cv_path_LD=/tools/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld
lt_cv_path_NM='/usr/bin/nm -B'
lt_cv_path_mainfest_tool=no
lt_cv_prog_compiler_c_o=yes
lt_cv_prog_compiler_pic='-fPIC -DPIC'
lt_cv_prog_compiler_pic_works=yes
lt_cv_prog_compiler_rtti_exceptions=no
lt_cv_prog_compiler_static_works=yes
lt_cv_prog_gnu_ld=yes
lt_cv_sharedlib_from_linklib_cmd='printf %s\n'
lt_cv_shlibpath_overrides_runpath=no
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_pipe='sed -n -e '\''s/^.*[   ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[     ][  ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 \2 \2/p'\'' | sed '\''/ __gnu_lto/d'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_c_name_address='sed -n -e '\''s/^: \([^ ]*\)[ ]*$/  {\"\1\", (void *) 0},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)$/  {"\2", (void *) \&\2},/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_c_name_address_lib_prefix='sed -n -e '\''s/^: \([^ ]*\)[ ]*$/  {\"\1\", (void *) 0},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* \([^ ]*\) \(lib[^ ]*\)$/  {"\2", (void *) \&\2},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)$/  {"lib\2", (void *) \&\2},/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_cdecl='sed -n -e '\''s/^T .* \(.*\)$/extern int \1();/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* .* \(.*\)$/extern char \1;/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_max_cmd_len=1572864
lt_cv_to_host_file_cmd=func_convert_file_noop
lt_cv_to_tool_file_cmd=func_convert_file_noop
mpfr_cv_c_long_double_format='IEEE extended, little endian'
mpfr_cv_errdivzero=no
mpfr_cv_gcc_floatconv_bug='yes, use -ffloat-store'
mpfr_cv_have_denorms=yes
mpfr_cv_have_fesetround=yes
mpfr_cv_have_intmax_max=yes
mpfr_cv_nanisnan=no

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
ALLOCA=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AR='ar'
AS='as'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='gawk'
CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
CCDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CFLAGS='-Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -ffloat-store'
CPP='gcc -std=gnu99 -E'
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DATAFILES=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL='dlltool'
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/tools/bin/grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
FGREP='/tools/bin/grep -F'
GREP='/tools/bin/grep'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD='/tools/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBMPFR_LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL='$(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool'
LIPO=''
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=':'
MKDIR_P='/tools/bin/mkdir -p'
MPFR_LDFLAGS=''
MPFR_LIBM='-lm'
NM='/usr/bin/nm -B'
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP='objdump'
OBJEXT='o'
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='mpfr'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='MPFR'
PACKAGE_STRING='MPFR 3.1.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='mpfr'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.1.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB='ranlib'
SED='/tools/bin/sed'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP='strip'
TUNE_LIBS=''
VERSION='3.1.2'
ac_ct_AR='ar'
ac_ct_CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep='_no'
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i686'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='/usr/share/doc/mpfr-3.1.2'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i686-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/tools/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "MPFR"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "mpfr"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.1.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "MPFR 3.1.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_LOCALE_H 1
#define HAVE_WCHAR_H 1
#define HAVE_STDARG 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
#define HAVE_ALLOCA_H 1
#define HAVE_ALLOCA 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_VA_COPY 1
#define HAVE_MEMMOVE 1
#define HAVE_MEMSET 1
#define HAVE_SETLOCALE 1
#define HAVE_STRTOL 1
#define HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY 1
#define HAVE_LONG_LONG 1
#define HAVE_INTMAX_T 1
#define MPFR_HAVE_INTMAX_MAX 1
#define MPFR_HAVE_FESETROUND 1
#define HAVE_DENORMS 1
#define HAVE_ROUND 1
#define HAVE_TRUNC 1
#define HAVE_FLOOR 1
#define HAVE_CEIL 1
#define HAVE_NEARBYINT 1
#define HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE 1
#define HAVE_LDOUBLE_IEEE_EXT_LITTLE 1
#define MPFR_USE_THREAD_SAFE 1
#define HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME 1
#define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
#define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
#define HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_MODE 1

configure: exit 1
```

Here is the config.log (my post was too big so trimmed the top off) ....

```
edantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -ffloat-store  conftest.c >&5
    configure:14478: $? = 0
    configure:14486: result: yes
    configure:14497: checking for recent GMP
    configure:14509: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -ffloat-store  conftest.c >&5
    configure:14509: $? = 0
    configure:14510: result: yes
    configure:14594: checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp
    configure:14619: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -ffloat-store   conftest.c -lgmp   >&5
    /tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    configure:14619: $? = 1
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
    | #define PACKAGE_NAME "MPFR"
    | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "mpfr"
    | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.1.2"
    | #define PACKAGE_STRING "MPFR 3.1.2"
    | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
    | #define PACKAGE_URL ""
    | #define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
    | #define STDC_HEADERS 1
    | #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
    | #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
    | #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
    | #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
    | #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
    | #define HAVE_LOCALE_H 1
    | #define HAVE_WCHAR_H 1
    | #define HAVE_STDARG 1
    | #define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
    | #define HAVE_ALLOCA_H 1
    | #define HAVE_ALLOCA 1
    | #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
    | #define HAVE_VA_COPY 1
    | #define HAVE_MEMMOVE 1
    | #define HAVE_MEMSET 1
    | #define HAVE_SETLOCALE 1
    | #define HAVE_STRTOL 1
    | #define HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY 1
    | #define HAVE_LONG_LONG 1
    | #define HAVE_INTMAX_T 1
    | #define MPFR_HAVE_INTMAX_MAX 1
    | #define MPFR_HAVE_FESETROUND 1
    | #define HAVE_DENORMS 1
    | #define HAVE_ROUND 1
    | #define HAVE_TRUNC 1
    | #define HAVE_FLOOR 1
    | #define HAVE_CEIL 1
    | #define HAVE_NEARBYINT 1
    | #define HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE 1
    | #define HAVE_LDOUBLE_IEEE_EXT_LITTLE 1
    | #define MPFR_USE_THREAD_SAFE 1
    | #define HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME 1
    | #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
    | #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
    | #define HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_MODE 1
    | /* end confdefs.h.  */
    | 
    | /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
    |    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
    |    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
    | #ifdef __cplusplus
    | extern "C"
    | #endif
    | char __gmpz_init ();
    | int
    | main ()
    | {
    | return __gmpz_init ();
    |   ;
    |   return 0;
    | }
    configure:14628: result: no
    configure:14633: error: libgmp not found or uses a different ABI (including static vs shared).
    Please read the INSTALL file -- see "In case of problem".

    ## ---------------- ##
    ## Cache variables. ##
    ## ---------------- ##

    ac_cv_build=i686-pc-linux-gnu
    ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
    ac_cv_c_const=yes
    ac_cv_c_volatile=yes
    ac_cv_env_CC_set=
    ac_cv_env_CC_value=
    ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
    ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
    ac_cv_func_alloca_works=yes
    ac_cv_func_gettimeofday=yes
    ac_cv_func_memmove=yes
    ac_cv_func_memset=yes
    ac_cv_func_setlocale=yes
    ac_cv_func_strtol=yes
    ac_cv_header_dlfcn_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_float_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_inttypes_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_limits_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_locale_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_memory_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_stdarg_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_stdc=yes
    ac_cv_header_stdint_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_stdlib_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_string_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_strings_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_sys_fpu_h=no
    ac_cv_header_sys_stat_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_sys_time_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_sys_types_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_time=yes
    ac_cv_header_unistd_h=yes
    ac_cv_header_wchar_h=yes
    ac_cv_host=i686-pc-linux-gnu
    ac_cv_lib_gmp___gmpz_init=no
    ac_cv_lib_m_main=yes
    ac_cv_objext=o
    ac_cv_path_EGREP='/tools/bin/grep -E'
    ac_cv_path_FGREP='/tools/bin/grep -F'
    ac_cv_path_GREP=/tools/bin/grep
    ac_cv_path_SED=/tools/bin/sed
    ac_cv_path_install='/tools/bin/install -c'
    ac_cv_path_mkdir=/tools/bin/mkdir
    ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
    ac_cv_prog_CPP='gcc -std=gnu99 -E'
    ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_AR=ar
    ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
    ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_DLLTOOL=dlltool
    ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_OBJDUMP=objdump
    ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_RANLIB=ranlib
    ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_STRIP=strip
    ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
    ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
    ac_cv_prog_cc_gcc_c_o=yes
    ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
    ac_cv_search_clock_gettime='none required'
    ac_cv_type_intmax_t=yes
    ac_cv_type_long_double=yes
    ac_cv_type_long_long_int=yes
    ac_cv_type_size_t=yes
    ac_cv_type_union_fpc_csr=no
    ac_cv_working_alloca_h=yes
    am_cv_CC_dependencies_compiler_type=gcc3
    gl_cv_size_max=yes
    gmp_cv_c_attribute_mode=yes
    lt_cv_ar_at_file=@
    lt_cv_archive_cmds_need_lc=no
    lt_cv_deplibs_check_method=pass_all
    lt_cv_file_magic_cmd='$MAGIC_CMD'
    lt_cv_file_magic_test_file=
    lt_cv_ld_reload_flag=-r
    lt_cv_nm_interface='BSD nm'
    lt_cv_objdir=.libs
    lt_cv_path_LD=/tools/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld
    lt_cv_path_NM='/usr/bin/nm -B'
    lt_cv_path_mainfest_tool=no
    lt_cv_prog_compiler_c_o=yes
    lt_cv_prog_compiler_pic='-fPIC -DPIC'
    lt_cv_prog_compiler_pic_works=yes
    lt_cv_prog_compiler_rtti_exceptions=no
    lt_cv_prog_compiler_static_works=yes
    lt_cv_prog_gnu_ld=yes
    lt_cv_sharedlib_from_linklib_cmd='printf %s\n'
    lt_cv_shlibpath_overrides_runpath=no
    lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_pipe='sed -n -e '\''s/^.*[   ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[     ][  ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 \2 \2/p'\'' | sed '\''/ __gnu_lto/d'\'''
    lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_c_name_address='sed -n -e '\''s/^: \([^ ]*\)[ ]*$/  {\"\1\", (void *) 0},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)$/  {"\2", (void *) \&\2},/p'\'''
    lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_c_name_address_lib_prefix='sed -n -e '\''s/^: \([^ ]*\)[ ]*$/  {\"\1\", (void *) 0},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* \([^ ]*\) \(lib[^ ]*\)$/  {"\2", (void *) \&\2},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)$/  {"lib\2", (void *) \&\2},/p'\'''
    lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_cdecl='sed -n -e '\''s/^T .* \(.*\)$/extern int \1();/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* .* \(.*\)$/extern char \1;/p'\'''
    lt_cv_sys_max_cmd_len=1572864
    lt_cv_to_host_file_cmd=func_convert_file_noop
    lt_cv_to_tool_file_cmd=func_convert_file_noop
    mpfr_cv_c_long_double_format='IEEE extended, little endian'
    mpfr_cv_errdivzero=no
    mpfr_cv_gcc_floatconv_bug='yes, use -ffloat-store'
    mpfr_cv_have_denorms=yes
    mpfr_cv_have_fesetround=yes
    mpfr_cv_have_intmax_max=yes
    mpfr_cv_nanisnan=no

    ## ----------------- ##
    ## Output variables. ##
    ## ----------------- ##

    ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
    ALLOCA=''
    AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
    AMDEP_FALSE='#'
    AMDEP_TRUE=''
    AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
    AR='ar'
    AS='as'
    AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run autoconf'
    AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run autoheader'
    AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run automake-1.11'
    AWK='gawk'
    CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
    CCDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
    CFLAGS='-Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -ffloat-store'
    CPP='gcc -std=gnu99 -E'
    CPPFLAGS=''
    CYGPATH_W='echo'
    DATAFILES=''
    DEFS=''
    DEPDIR='.deps'
    DLLTOOL='dlltool'
    DSYMUTIL=''
    DUMPBIN=''
    ECHO_C=''
    ECHO_N='-n'
    ECHO_T=''
    EGREP='/tools/bin/grep -E'
    EXEEXT=''
    FGREP='/tools/bin/grep -F'
    GREP='/tools/bin/grep'
    INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
    INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
    INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
    INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
    LD='/tools/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld'
    LDFLAGS=''
    LIBMPFR_LDFLAGS=''
    LIBOBJS=''
    LIBS=''
    LIBTOOL='$(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool'
    LIPO=''
    LN_S='ln -s'
    LTLIBOBJS=''
    MAINT=''
    MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE='#'
    MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
    MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/missing --run makeinfo'
    MANIFEST_TOOL=':'
    MKDIR_P='/tools/bin/mkdir -p'
    MPFR_LDFLAGS=''
    MPFR_LIBM='-lm'
    NM='/usr/bin/nm -B'
    NMEDIT=''
    OBJDUMP='objdump'
    OBJEXT='o'
    OTOOL64=''
    OTOOL=''
    PACKAGE='mpfr'
    PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
    PACKAGE_NAME='MPFR'
    PACKAGE_STRING='MPFR 3.1.2'
    PACKAGE_TARNAME='mpfr'
    PACKAGE_URL=''
    PACKAGE_VERSION='3.1.2'
    PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
    RANLIB='ranlib'
    SED='/tools/bin/sed'
    SET_MAKE=''
    SHELL='/bin/sh'
    STRIP='strip'
    TUNE_LIBS=''
    VERSION='3.1.2'
    ac_ct_AR='ar'
    ac_ct_CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
    ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
    am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
    am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
    am__fastdepCC_FALSE='#'
    am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
    am__include='include'
    am__isrc=''
    am__leading_dot='.'
    am__nodep='_no'
    am__quote=''
    am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
    am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
    bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
    build='i686-pc-linux-gnu'
    build_alias=''
    build_cpu='i686'
    build_os='linux-gnu'
    build_vendor='pc'
    datadir='${datarootdir}'
    datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
    docdir='/usr/share/doc/mpfr-3.1.2'
    dvidir='${docdir}'
    exec_prefix='NONE'
    host='i686-pc-linux-gnu'
    host_alias=''
    host_cpu='i686'
    host_os='linux-gnu'
    host_vendor='pc'
    htmldir='${docdir}'
    includedir='${prefix}/include'
    infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
    install_sh='${SHELL} /sources/mpfr-3.1.2/install-sh'
    libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
    libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
    localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
    localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
    mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
    mkdir_p='/tools/bin/mkdir -p'
    oldincludedir='/usr/include'
    pdfdir='${docdir}'
    prefix='/usr'
    program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
    psdir='${docdir}'
    sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
    sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
    sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
    target_alias=''

    ## ----------- ##
    ## confdefs.h. ##
    ## ----------- ##

    /* confdefs.h */
    #define PACKAGE_NAME "MPFR"
    #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "mpfr"
    #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.1.2"
    #define PACKAGE_STRING "MPFR 3.1.2"
    #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
    #define PACKAGE_URL ""
    #define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
    #define STDC_HEADERS 1
    #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
    #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
    #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
    #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
    #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
    #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
    #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
    #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
    #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
    #define HAVE_LOCALE_H 1
    #define HAVE_WCHAR_H 1
    #define HAVE_STDARG 1
    #define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
    #define HAVE_ALLOCA_H 1
    #define HAVE_ALLOCA 1
    #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
    #define HAVE_VA_COPY 1
    #define HAVE_MEMMOVE 1
    #define HAVE_MEMSET 1
    #define HAVE_SETLOCALE 1
    #define HAVE_STRTOL 1
    #define HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY 1
    #define HAVE_LONG_LONG 1
    #define HAVE_INTMAX_T 1
    #define MPFR_HAVE_INTMAX_MAX 1
    #define MPFR_HAVE_FESETROUND 1
    #define HAVE_DENORMS 1
    #define HAVE_ROUND 1
    #define HAVE_TRUNC 1
    #define HAVE_FLOOR 1
    #define HAVE_CEIL 1
    #define HAVE_NEARBYINT 1
    #define HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE 1
    #define HAVE_LDOUBLE_IEEE_EXT_LITTLE 1
    #define MPFR_USE_THREAD_SAFE 1
    #define HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME 1
    #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
    #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
    #define HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_MODE 1

    configure: exit 1
```

Comment: I should add that my host is Ubuntu 12 and I am in the LFS chroot system.

Answer (score 2):

If you already built gmp and all gmp libraries are in /usr/lib then try below command.

as `checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... no
configure: error: libgmp not found` this says gmp libraries are not able link ,so proper way to avoid error is use `--with-gmp={path to installed gmp libraries}

`./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-thread-safe --docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpfr-3.1.2
--with-gmp=/usr/lib`

If not 1st build GMP libararies.

Comment: I did build the gmp (6.14) and they do exist.

{make check 2>&1 | tee gmp-check-log
awk '/tests passed/{total+=$2} ; END{print total}' gmp-check-log}

does show 185.
Adding the "--with-gmp=/usr/lib" did not change anything.

Comment: what prefix you given to GMP while building?

Comment: if --prefix=/usr for gmp then add `--with-gmp=/usr/` for mpfr

Comment: @vinayhunachyal: Is this [post](http://pmc.polytechnique.fr/pagesperso/dc/arm-en.html) a correct way to go about? Refer to the g and h sections. I am getting `configure: error: libgmp not found or uses a different ABI.` error. Kindly help. Thanks!